# Pandas Combine date and time columns

Tags: pandas, datetime

Having an issue making one datetime column. My df has a 'date' column with the date as a tuple, and a timestamp column. As shown below:

```
df.head(2)
     date       time
0    (2016,5,7) 01:01:01.125
1    (2016,5,8) 02:03:05.691
```

Is there a quick way in pandas to combine these two columns into one datetime column handling for the fact that the date is in a tuple?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Construct a dataframe from the tuples to pass to `pd.to_datetime`
Convert the `'time`' column to time deltas with `pd.to_timedelta`

```
date = pd.to_datetime(
    pd.DataFrame(
        df.date.tolist(),
        columns=['year', 'month', 'day']
    )
)

time = pd.to_timedelta(df.time)

date + time

0   2016-05-07 01:01:01.125
1   2016-05-08 02:03:05.691
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```